# Programmatically change button text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am trying to programmatically change a button title's text, (the button is attached to an IBoutlet) but whenever I try to do the code `_button.titlelabel = @"example text"`
it doesnt work! Please help me! (objective-c)

Comment: Use text property to assign text value for button or label.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it should be like this :

For Objective C :

```
[_button setTitle:@"example text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For Swift :

```
_button.setTitle("example Text", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

titleLabel's `text` property has no effect. Instead, use `-setTitle:forState:` on the button like below:

```
[_button setTitle:@"example text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

See the documentation for UIButton's titleLabel property:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uibutton?language=objc

Answer (score 0):

You can set the title of a button like this

```
 [_button setTitle:@"example text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

And if you want to get the title of a button you can use like this

```
NSString *getTittle = _button.titlelabel.text;
```